# @tensorflow/tfjs-node installation failed in windows system

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, tensorflow.js

I am using node version v10.24.1, win 10 OS, VSCode IDE. while install @tensorflow/tfjs-node npm package it throws me error.

```
node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v7/3.10.0/CPU-windows-3.10.0.zip
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.10.0 and node@10.24.1 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v7/3.10.0/CPU-windows-3.10.0.zip
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.31729.503) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - "Visual Studio C++ core features" missing
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at findVisualStudio2015 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at regSearchKeys (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at regGetValue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:301:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=E:\\learning\\ReactJS\\nextapp\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v7\\tfjs_binding.node" "--module_name=tfjs_binding" "--module_path=E:\\learning\\ReactJS\\nextapp\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v7" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=7" "--node_napi_label=napi-v7"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\learning\ReactJS\nextapp\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
gyp ERR! node -v v10.24.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=E:\learning\ReactJS\nextapp\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v7\tfjs_binding.node --module_name=tfjs_binding --module_path=E:\learning\ReactJS\nextapp\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v7 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=7 --node_napi_label=napi-v7' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.cmd.on (E:\learning\ReactJS\nextapp\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\learning\\ReactJS\\nextapp\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd E:\learning\ReactJS\nextapp\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.24.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.14.5 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@4.33.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-next@11.1.2 requires a peer of eslint@^7.23.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@6.4.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.26.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-hooks@4.2.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @next/swc-darwin-x64@11.1.2 (node_modules\@next\swc-darwin-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @next/swc-darwin-x64@11.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @next/swc-darwin-arm64@11.1.2 (node_modules\@next\swc-darwin-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @next/swc-darwin-arm64@11.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @next/swc-linux-x64-gnu@11.1.2 (node_modules\@next\swc-linux-x64-gnu):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @next/swc-linux-x64-gnu@11.1.2: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.10.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.10.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AMIT\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-27T07_04_56_747Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

> node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v7/3.10.0/CPU-windows-3.10.0.zip

node 10 is obsolete. node 16 is current and node 14 is lts.
this is not just cosmetic, that has a major impact on how binary bindings to external libraries are done. so `napi` **v7** version of binaries is no longer pre-packaged.

Comment: I got same error after update my node from 10 to 16 but still facing same issue I guess this is not node error it may be vscode c++ build library error.

Comment: you should never be required to build tfjs-node from sources, issue is that pre-build binary is not found: `node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v7/3.10.0/CPU-windows-3.10.0.zip`